# WCF and using WEBGET to test service in browser

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, wcf, webget

Hi I am very new to using WCF (half a day old) and I have created a service which I can see via localhost

http://localhost:[port]/Service1.svc? - no 404!

However, before I want to connect to this service via an application, I want to see if the service does actually return what is meant to. (Just making sure the database connection is OK etc)

I have this on my IService (unfortunately it is in VB.Net, but I do know C#..)

```
<OperationContract>
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="/method/{parameter}")>
Function getData(ByVal parameter As Integer) As String
```

And this of course fires (or should) the method getData in the service1.svc class.

So firing up the webservice, I tried to do this...

> http://localhost:61094/Service1.svc?method/1

and

> http://localhost:61094/Service1.svc/method/1

However nothing. (doesnt debug on the code either)

Looking around, It could be do with my web config file which I haven't touched.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting up an explicit service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="WebApplication1.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.IService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>    
</configuration>
```

and then have a contract:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService
    <OperationContract>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="/method/{parameter}")>
    Function getData(ByVal parameter As String) As String
End Interface
```

and an implementation:

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService

    Public Function getData(ByVal parameter As String) As String Implements IService.getData
        Return "Foo bar"
    End Function
End Class
```

Now navigating to `/Service1.svc/method/123` will invoke the proper method.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, quick question as I dont want to really post a new question, I am doing this service to show that some functionality can work, the webservice will actually be developed by a third party, however, it is going to be a SOAP Web Service, so basically to make it a SOAP I changed the endpoint binding from webHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding, does this now make it a SOAP service?

Comment: Yes, changing from `webHttpBinding` to `basicHttpBinding` makes it a `SOAP` service.